# Why do android docs want me to import play services as a project and not as a lib?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am going to use Google Play Services in my android application. I have no problem there, however I do have a theoretical question...

In the Google docs for the API it says you must import the Project source from the SDK, and not the *.Jar file as a lib ([Google Play Services setup docs](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)).

This is fine, but I find it more natural to just add a reference to the *.jar file in there.

My question therefore is: Is there a reason Google says we must do this? if not I'd rather just reference the *.jar file.

Thanks, Jason

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google Play Service contains resources (layout, images, etc.) that cannot be included in a jar file. This is linked to the way the framework compute all the XML resources of your project to give them unique IDs.

This is why you have to import a library project instead of simply including a jar dependency.

Comment: Ok, thanks good to know. Wish they would find a better way to do it though. I hate adding the source to their code

Comment: I think the new Gradle based build system they announced during Google I/O this year should resolve this issue. Not sure if it ready for production yet though.

Comment: Yea, seems like the new AAR binary format will resolve this, good to know, hope to see it soon.